# Different in Load <div/> and <div></div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs which I´m doing a load by Ajax in everyone. If I write both like this.

```
<div id="informCandidacyId"/>
<div id="idDivFiles"/>
```

The load process of both happens because I can debug the calls to my controllers, but onyl one view is added to the DOM.

In the other hand if I write the divs like this.

```
<div id="informCandidacyId"></div>
<div id="idDivFiles"></div>
```

The both load calls works perfectly.

So my question is, what is the difference when we are loading html code between close the tag in the declaration or do it in another tag?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: what is doctype in html?

Comment: After your page loads, check the rendered HTML in source-view to see how the browser has interpreted your self-closing divs.

Comment: Post the code you're using.

Comment: Div's are not valid self closing tags

Comment: [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5).

Comment: Divs aren't self closing, so your page wouldn't validate. Just do it the correct way.

Comment: @Satpal any reason for that?, and in that case why is allowed defined as self closing?

Comment: @j08691, Just for http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262221/why-other-usergold-badge-holder-close-vote-closed-question-instantly, Did you voted to close the question as duplicate

Comment: @Satpal - Must've been something other than duplicate. I don't recall right now though.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `<div>` is not a self closing tag. While some browsers may accept and correct your code, it won't validate, and is bad practice.

[W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-div-element)

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML5 [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags), the `<div>` element is a [normal element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#normal-elements) and only [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) (like `<br>`) or [foreign elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#foreign-elements) (from MathML and SVG namespace) could have a "/" (U+002F) character in the start tag.

So your code is invalid and this explains the difference in the load process.